# select distinct xelement based on attribute

Tags: xml, linq, lambda, distinct, xelement

```
  <field name="value" value="A" />
  <field name="value" value="B" />
  <field name="text" value="C" />
  <field name="text" value="D" />
  <field name="key" value="E" />
```

When I filter I need to get one element for "value", one element for "text" and one element for "key" (Yes, "key" has only one element and it should be returned)

I tried

```
 elements.Select(item=>item.Attribute("name")).Distinct();
```

This returns only the XAttribute but I need the entire XElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need `DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/):

```
var distinct = elements.DistinctBy(x => x.Attribute("name").Value);
```